# Ruby on Rails, missing FROM-clause entry for table "pages"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

trying to resolve this pesky bug after converting a Rails app from 3.0 to 4.29

I've got a Scope attached to the model PostType that's complaining it needs  access to the model Pages, here's the original code:

```
class PostType < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_domain, lambda { 
    |domain| includes([:pages]).where("pages.domain LIKE ?", domain) 
  }
```

It's throwing up this error message:

```
  PostType Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "post_types".* FROM "post_types" WHERE (pages.domain LIKE 'test.com')
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "pages"
LINE 1: SELECT "post_types".* FROM "post_types" WHERE (pages.domain ...
                                                       ^
: SELECT "post_types".* FROM "post_types" WHERE (pages.domain LIKE 'test.com')
```

Now I can resolve it with old fashioned SQL:

```
SELECT "post_types".* FROM "post_types", "pages" WHERE (pages.domain LIKE 'test.com')
```

Which works but I have no idea how to translate that to Rails, little bit rusty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The way you are querying `post_types` requires an explicit reference to the `pages` table. Omitting `references` will not `JOIN` the `pages` table which results in an error.

```
  scope :by_domain, lambda { 
    |domain| includes([:pages]).where("pages.domain LIKE ?", domain).references(:pages) 
  }
```

This basically tells the Rails ORM that the query string references the `pages` table, so it will add a join.

Take a look  at the [API documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references)